# CDF and ElasticSearch

Tags: programming, cdfplayer

I have an large amount of data, in the terabyte range, in an ElasticSearch instance. The data is on an network air gapped from my Mathematica instance and I'd like to have an app to examine the data in ElasticSearch. Is there any way of reading and writing to an ElasticSearch instance from a deployed CDF?

Comment: Not with a FreePlayer but you can use PlayerPro or enterprise CDFs.